# Cordova iOS Simulator tel and mailto not working

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, mailto, tel

I am unable to initiate the call and mailto via href on my iOS Cordova app. For the code:

```
<a href="tel:XXX">Call</a>
```

I get the error in the Xcode console as

```
There is no registered handler for URL scheme tel.
```

Same for mailto. How can this be fixed? I've added these to config.xml.

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="sms:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="market:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

I'm using Cordova v6.0.0, Xcode v7.2.1 and developing for iOS v9.2.

Comment: It is a simulator and not a real device. Mail and the phone.app are not installed on the simulator, so you can't use them. Test your app on a real device!

Comment: thats the missing feature of iOS Simulator.So try it with device.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Restating the comments above - use a real device not the simulator.